# how to implement table inheritance in GreenDao

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

I've been trying to create a database where all the tables inherit a certain element in order to have to possibility to have meta-data.

there for I added in the model generator in all the table declarations this line:

```
public Entity addSuperEntity(Schema schema) {
     Entity superEntity = schema.addEntity("superEntity");
     superEntity.addIdProperty().primaryKey();
     // SET RELATIONSHIP 1:m TO META DATA
}

public Entity addTable(Schema schema) {
    Entity mEntity = schema.addEntity("MyEntity");
    mEntity.setSuper("superEntity");
    mEntity.addIdProperty().PrimaryKey();
    // REST OF FIELDS
}
```

the question is:

now after I generated this to my Android project, how can I make sure that this still happens in real life? do I need to change anything now?

the official documentation doesn't have anything about inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance is supported for non-entity super classes using setSuperclass(String). An alternative is implementing interfaces using implementsInterface(String).

I updated the official docs with some details in the new section on inheritance and interfaces:
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/