# greendao setting superclass

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

I have tried setting a BasePost class as a superclass of MyPost, however, the properties from the BasePost was not inherited and is not present in the table created for MyPost. Am I doing something wrong, or it really is not possible to automatically create properties inherited by a subclass.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069614/how-to-implement-table-inheritance-in-greendao

Comment: BasePost is not an entity created via greendao so I assume it is ok to use it as a superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the superclass is a greendao entity or not. Only the properties that are defined for your actual entity will be persited by greendao.

If you define a superclass you "just" have the functionality of this class. The member-variables of the superclass will not be persisted.

Comment: Seems like it. Thanks for confirming.